# How to bind part of form values to model in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms, model-binding

I inherited an asp.net webform application. Now when I try to add new feature to it. I hit the following stop:

I created a form to get data from end user, and the data goes into two tables in the database.

I used Entity Framework to deal with communication with database.

My question is, because the form data need to go into two models(two tables), can I bind one model to part of the form data?
Or there is no way to do that, I have to go through each and every form data and assign them to the model properties?

for example
data model would be

```
class ModelA{ 
  public int ModelAID {get;set;} 
  public string ModelAName {get;set;}
}
class ModelB{
  public int ModelBID {get;set;}
  public string ModelBName{get;set;}
}
```

front end page would be

```
<form>
   <input name="Aid"/>
   <input name="AName"/>
   <input name="Bid"/>
   <input name="BName"/>
</form>
```

code behide would be

Answer (score 0):

What kind of version are you using?
I'm developing in web forms 4.5, and I have suffered with the similar problem.

The short answer is.. kinda difficult but you can do it with some restrictions.

For data binding, I'm not sure what you mean.. 
if you want to just bring the data, or you want to update and delete the data as well.

For me, I am using gridview everywhere to show the data and also to update, delete it, and in my experience, updating and delete is possible for one table.

But you could show other table's data by showing it in ItemTemplate.

Here is a short example of what i did :

```
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ItemType="model"
        ID="someGrid" SelectMethod="someGrid_GetData" CellPadding ="10"
        autoGenerateColumns="false" deleteMethod="someGrid_DeleteItem"
        updateMethod="someGrid_UpdateItem" DataKeyNames="id"
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true">
                <Columns>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="col1"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="col2" HeaderText="col2" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="details">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="detailLink" runat="server" Text="details" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/someDetails?some=" + Eval("someDetails") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="vendor">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="vendorLbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

as you can see, you could update, delete the data from model table, but you can also put data inside vendor as a label from the code behind.

I've spent many time figuring about this. 
And hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to update the data from one form to two database tables.  So it is more of using the TryUpdateModel method twice, but each time just using part of the form data. I updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry don't know about that. Tell me if you find out. Honestly, I am not sure we can do it.